# Ошибка в Unity 2019.3.2f1

Tags: unity3d

По середине компиляции проэкта для play маркет поймал такую ошибку, второй день пытаюсь её исправить и не получается. Буду ОЧЕНЬ благодарен если поможете.
[Ошибка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giksK.png)  [Настройки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kb8d.png) [Настройки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cc7i.png) [Настройки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7ftw.png)

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00275] in <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0    at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0  UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Win32Exception: ApplicationName='D:\приложение\2019.3.2f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe', CommandLine='--convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks
--enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARMv7" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="C:\Users\kopyl\Desktop\get up from your knees — копия (3)\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a\libil2cpp.so"
--cachedirectory="C:\Users\kopyl\Desktop\get up from your knees — копия (3)\Assets\..\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache"
--additional-include-directories="D:/приложение/2019.3.2f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="D:/приложение/2019.3.2f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include"
--tool-chain-path="D:/приложение/2019.3.2f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK"
--profiler-report --map-file-parser="D:/приложение/2019.3.2f1/Editor/Data/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe"
--directory="C:/Users/kopyl/Desktop/get up from your knees — копия (3)/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed"
--generatedcppdir="C:/Users/kopyl/Desktop/get up from your knees — копия (3)/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput" ', CurrentDirectory='C:\Users\kopyl\Desktop\get up from your knees — копия (3)\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed', Native error= Запрошенная операция требует повышения.

System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) (at <ae22a4e8f83c41d69684ae7f557133d9>:0) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () (at <ae22a4e8f83c41d69684ae7f557133d9>:0) (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start (System.EventHandler exitCallback) (at <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0) UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start () (at <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0) UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0) UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (UnityEditor.Il2Cpp.Il2CppBuildPipelineData data, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory, System.Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) (at <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <501fdf9059b849939e0297808b46ab08>:0) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <501fdf9059b849939e0297808b46ab08>:0) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <501fdf9059b849939e0297808b46ab08>:0) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <501fdf9059b849939e0297808b46ab08>:0) UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: Добавьте ошибку и другие необходимые данные (для понимания) прямо в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

"Запрошенная операция требует повышения." - запустите Editor от имени администратора.

Так же часто сталкивался с различными ошибками при билде, если в пути есть русские символы. Переименуйте вашу директорию "get up from your knees — копия (3)" и "приложение" тоже на всякий случай.